# How to add legend for filled and unfilled regions?

Tags: plotting, functions, legending, labeling

I have the following plot.
How I add the legend for the filled, not-filled regions and the boundary line with the names "above", "below" and "boundary line", respectively?
Something similiar to the graph below. The idea looks simple but I couldn't figure out how to label for a region.

```
Show[
 Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic],
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], Filling -> Top, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.75, LightGray]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Legended[Show[
  Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic], 
  ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], 
   Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.75, LightGray]]], 
 Placed[Column@{SwatchLegend[{Opacity[.5, LightGray], White}, 
     {"Above", "Below"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 25], 
    LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Dashed, Red]}, {"Boundary"}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 25]}, Right]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `LineLegend` with the (undocumented) option `"LegendItem"` to inject desired glyphs as legend icons:

```
linelegend = LineLegend[{Opacity[.5, LightGray], Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], White},
  {"Above", "Boundary", "Below"}, 
  "LegendItem" -> {"Square", Automatic, "Square"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 25]
```

[image]

and use `linelegend` as the setting for  `PlotLegends` in any of the plots in `Show`:

```
Show[Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotLegends -> linelegend], 
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], 
  Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.75, LightGray]]]
```

[image]

The second approach is quite convenient for using arbitrary graphics objects/images as legend icons, including several built-in objects (like `"Square"`, `"Curve"`, `"Doodle"` and `"MarkerCluster"`) and built-in `ChartElementData` objects (like, for instance, `"TriangleWaveBubble"`, `"NoiseBubble"`, `"SquareWaveBubble"`, etc.):

```
styles = Prepend[Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed]]@(ColorData[97] /@ Range[9]);

labels = {"Automatic", "Square", "Curve", "Doodle", "MarkerCluster", 
   "NoiseBubble", "SquareWaveBubble", "TriangleWaveBubble", 
   "Mandrill", "FreakedSmiley"};

legenditems = {Automatic, "Square", "Curve", "Doodle", 
   "MarkerCluster", ChartElementData["NoiseBubble"], 
   ChartElementData["SquareWaveBubble"], 
   ChartElementData["TriangleWaveBubble"], 
   ImageMultiply[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], ColorData[97]@8], 
   Graphics[{ColorData[97]@9, Text@Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", 62]}]};

LineLegend[styles, labels, "LegendItem" -> legenditems, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 50, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You could also include `Opacity` in the legend to get a closer match.

Comment: Thank you @BobHanlon; updated with your suggestion.